# Open URL in textView link

Tags: java, android, textview

I wanted to open http://www.google.com when click to textview link. But it launches browser but in address bar it display wwww.google.com%27 and it produces error. Please provide solution.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  textView.setClickable(true);
  textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  String text="<a 'href=http://www.google.com'> Click to open Google!!! </a>";
  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set text by code using Html to encode/decode the text

```
Html.fromHtml(string)
```

Comment: Hi I am beginner, dont know how to enccode/decode the text. Could you please explain

Comment: try something like this 'Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<a 'href=http://www.google.com'> Click to open Google!!! </a>]]>");'

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:linkify="web"` in your textview element in xml. This will open up the browser.